# Traefik: Simple Letsencrypt HTTPS redirect to whoami service throws "404 page not found"

Tags: docker-compose, traefik, traefik-ingress

I've tried to get this up and running for two days now and some simple HTTP -> HTTPs redirect does not work! :(

Pretty simple use case:

whoami.my-example-domain.com:80 => redirect to whoami.my-example-domain.com:443 and then traefik internally redirects to :80 of my whoami service docker container.

Here's the docker-compose.yml

```
version: "3"
services:
  reverse-proxy:
image: traefik:alpine
command:
  - --logLevel=WARN
  - --defaultentrypoints=http,https
  - --entrypoints=Name:http Address::80 Redirect.EntryPoint:https
  - --entrypoints=Name:https Address::443 TLS
  - --acme
  - --acme.email=myemail@gmail.com
  - --acme.storage=acme.json
  - --acme.entryPoint=https
  - --acme.httpChallenge.entryPoint=http
  - --acme.OnHostRule=true
  - --acme.onDemand=false
  - --acme.acmeLogging=true
  - --docker
  - --docker.watch
  - --docker.exposedbydefault=false
  - --docker.domain=docker.localhost
restart: always
networks:
  - web
ports:
  - "80:80"     # The HTTP port
  - "443:443"   # The HTTPS port
volumes:
  - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock # So that Traefik can listen to the Docker events
  - /opt/data/traefik/acme.json:/acme.json
  whoami:
image: containous/whoami  # A container that exposes an API to show its IP address
labels:
  - "traefik.enable=true"
  - "traefik.frontend.rule=Host:whoami.some-example-domain.com"
  - "traefik.port=80"
  - "traefik.frontend.entryPoints=http"
networks:
  web:
    external: true
```

When I now call http://whoami.some-example-domain.com (this is just a demo domain and won't work) => it redirects to HTTPs... which is cool, but then it throws the famous "404 page not found" traefik standard error.

If already tried to set the following labels to the container:

> - "traefik.port=80"
> - "traefik.frontend.entryPoints=http"

That didn't work either.

Any help would be appreciated! Thanks in advance!

Regards,

Sascha

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to remove `traefik.frontend.entryPoints` (linked to `defaultentrypoints`) or use `traefik.frontend.entryPoints=http,https`

```
version: "3"

services:
  reverse-proxy:
    image: traefik:v1.7.8
    command:
      - --logLevel=WARN
      - --defaultentrypoints=http,https
      - --entrypoints=Name:http Address::80 Redirect.EntryPoint:https
      - --entrypoints=Name:https Address::443 TLS
      - --acme
      - --acme.email=myemail@gmail.com
      - --acme.storage=acme.json
      - --acme.entryPoint=https
      - --acme.httpChallenge.entryPoint=http
      - --acme.OnHostRule=true
      - --acme.onDemand=false
      - --acme.acmeLogging=true
      - --docker
      - --docker.exposedbydefault=false
      - --docker.domain=some-example-domain.com
    restart: always
    networks:
      - web
    ports:
      - "80:80"     # The HTTP port
      - "443:443"   # The HTTPS port
    volumes:
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock # So that Traefik can listen to the Docker events
      - /opt/data/traefik/acme.json:/acme.json
  whoami:
    image: containous/whoami  # A container that exposes an API to show its IP address
    labels:
      - "traefik.enable=true"
      - "traefik.frontend.rule=Host:some-example-domain.com"
    networks:
     - web

networks:
  web:
    external: true
```

Comment: Hi, been there already. If I remove "traefik.frontend.entryPoints" I get a Gateway Timeout. But thanks to the hint... I'm pretty sure it's related to this somehow, but I couldn't fint out what causes this problem.

Comment: If I use yours, it works for me as well. It looks like I've missed the networks part! F*ck! So the containers were to able to communicate at all... Thanks so much!